# How can I get Google Hangouts to start minimized?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, google-chrome-extensions, google-hangouts

I have the desktop (i.e. Chrome extension) version of Hangouts—it starts up whenever I launch Chrome. How can I get it to start minimised? (It can be minimised manually by clicking on the X that appears when hovered over, and then choosing the "minimise" option, but I am looking for an automatic solution.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options of installing Hangouts from the Chrome Web Store on your computer. I suspect you have the Hangouts App installed.

- [Hangouts (App)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl)
- [Hangouts (Extension)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd)

[image: Screenshot of Hangouts App and Extension in the Chrome Web Store]

You can disable the app (or remove it altogether) and try the Hangouts Extension. The Hangouts Extension will start when Chrome starts minimized in the notification area of your Windows taskbar.

You activate it by clicking it.

[image: Hangouts Extension in the Windows Notification Area]

You trade-off the standalone app experience if you switch to the Hangouts extension.

Answer (score 1):

If the Hangouts extension is installed instead of the Hangouts app, open Chrome and follow these steps to allow the extension to automatically run when you log into Windows without needing to open Chrome first.

1. Open Chrome
2. Open Settings (Press Alt-E and click Settings)
3. Scroll to the bottom of the Settings and click 'Show advanced settings...'
4. Find and check the option 'Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed'

Test by logging out of Windows and logging back in. The Hangouts extension icon should be visible in the system tray even without opening Chrome first.